# Go Lang simple regexp MatchString not working? Returns true when expecting false. Why?

Tags: regex, go

The following code prints true. It should return false shouldn't it?

```
package main

import "regexp"
import "fmt"

func main() {
  res, _ := regexp.MatchString("[a-z][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*", "%s")
  fmt.Println(res)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/A_x5WID9wl

Comment: Why should it return no match? It finds `s`. Add anchors to enforce the entire string match, `\`^[a-z][0-9a-zA-Z_$]*$\``.

Comment: I think its too late for me. Exhaustion is setting in for me. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you expecting what [FindString](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindString) does?